# MLE under Gaussian Noise

Tags: maximum-likelihood

$$Y_i = \theta + N_i\quad,\, i=1,\ldots,n\,,$$  where  $\theta$  is an unknown parameter and  $N_i$  are i.i.d Gaussian random variables with zero mean.

Would the ML estimator of  $\theta$  change if the  $N_i$ 's are independent Gaussians with possibly different variances  $\sigma^2_1,\ldots,\sigma^2_n$  but same zero mean? $\sigma^2_i$  are known constants.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math.

Comment: Sounds like homework, so please use `[self-study]` tag and tell us how did you try solving it and what kind of help do you need?

Answer (score 0):

The log-likelihood (with possibly different variances) is
     log(1,…,|,21,…,2)=−12∑=1log(22)−∑=1(−)222.
Note that here we cannot take  2  out of the summation. Thus, to solve this, we need to take the derivative of the log-likelihood with respect to    set it equal to zero.

Doing so, we obtain
     ∑2    =∑12,
which yields
     ̂=∑2∑12,
which is not necessarily the same estimator as before. That is, the sample average of   's is no longer the ML estimate of   .

Comment: It will be easier to read this answer if you use math typesetting. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simple processing of the outputs $Y_i's$ to obtain $R_i's$ as given by $R_i =Y_i/\sigma_i$. Now, $R_i's$ have the same variance for all $i$ though the mean is now $\frac{\Theta}{\sigma_i}$. If you write the likelihood function based on $R_i's$, the ML estimate for this problem boils down to

$$ arg\min_\limits{\Theta} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(R_i -\Theta/\sigma_i\right)^2$$.

Taking derivative w.r.t to $\Theta$, we get $$\Theta_{est}=\frac{\sum_{i}R_i/\sigma_i}{\sum_{i}1/\sigma_i^2}=\frac{\sum_{i}Y_i/\sigma_i^2}{\sum_{i}1/\sigma_i^2}$$.

Answer (score -2):

$\theta$ won't change. By writing down the log likelihood function $L(\theta)$ and making $\partial L(\theta) / \partial \theta=0$, you'll get:$$\sum_i (\theta_i -y_i)/\sigma_i^2=0 \implies \frac{n}{\sum_i \sigma_i^2} \theta = \frac{\sum_i y_i}{\sum_i \sigma_i^2} \implies \theta = \frac{\sum_i y_i}{n}$$

Comment: The log-likelihood (with possibly different variances) is
   log(1,…,|,21,…,2)=−12∑=1log(22)−∑=1(−)222.     
Note that here we cannot take  2  out of the summation. Thus, to solve this, we need to take the derivative of the log-likelihood with respect to    set it equal to zero.

Doing so, we obtain
   ∑2   =∑12,     
which yields
   ̂=∑2∑12,     
which is not necessarily the same estimator as before. That is, the sample average of   's is no longer the ML estimate of   .